# Processing Error regarding Contributions

Tags: processing

I am trying to load libraries / modes / tools into Processing and nothing is working, all I get is:

```
Error in contribution listing file on line 1
```

regardless of which type I'm trying to import. I see that this issue has affected others ([here](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2803)) but I cannot seem to resolve this issue and I really am starting to love working in Processing. I want to start to apply this knowledge to Android but I can't, and I even tried to manually import the Android tools and it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Version of processing?

Comment: @v.k. 2.2.1 Windows 8 64 Bit on an i7 with 8 GB ram and a Nvidia 860M GPU

Comment: I have the same version (in a mac), and I have the same warning, but I haven't noticed because the things are installed even with the warning showing up... Perhaps you should report this at github...

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if this is a new issue affecting some others users on 2.2.1 ([see here](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/7731/error-in-contribution-listing-file-on-line-1/p1)) and there is currently a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2908) so hopefully it will be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a proxy issue.
I changed my network proxy to automatic in ubuntu 14.04. And the file contrib.txt file got automatically generated on restart and it started working.